# La página ha rechazado la conexión

Tags: iframe

Hola buenas es bastante breve mi problema resulta que estoy usando la siguiente opción de boostrap para poner un video en mi pagina web pero pongo bien el link del video todo e probado con mas videos etc pero no hay caso que se quite ese mensaje de que la pagina web rechazo la conexión, siendo que en el mismo boostrap esta el ejemplo puesto con un video de YouTube, de ante mano muchas gracias.

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CkqsrL9y1BY&t=1s&ab_channel=MuniHualp%C3%A9n" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
  </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El detalle está en la url del video, ya que tiene que ser de tipo embebido para que el iframe responda

En tu caso sería

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CkqsrL9y1BY" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Para conseguir esta liga en el sitio de youtube, en las opciones de compartir tiene que seleccionar la parte de insertar y copiar la url del iframe que te entrega

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta fue la solución muchísimas gracias bro.

Comment: Hola @BryanJoséM79 Cuando una respuesta te resulte útil **debes marcarla como aceptada** para que otros usuarios que tengan una duda o problema similar sepan que les puede servir.

Answer (score 2):

También debes recordar que solo puedes embeber vídeos público y que no tengan restricción para compartir en otras páginas, asimismo, puedes obtener ese código para insertar en tu página haciendo click derecho en el vídeo que estas reproduciendo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés leer [ask], ya que la misma parece un comentario y no una respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

No se si es el caso, pero por ahi ayuda.

Por si les sirve en html (formulario login en un iframe) y PHP que valida. Si metes un iframe y salis de él a otra página (por ejemplo a un php que te valida usuario y password) , al volver a veces te rechaza la conexión.
Modifica archivo Htaccess.php en la carpeta C:\xampp\php\pear\File

Mete esta linea con tus datos de tus archivos.

Redirect 301 "/old_url.html" "/new_url.html"

Info en : https://es.semrush.com/blog/archivo-htaccess/

Verifica la configuración de tu servidor web para asegurarte de que está permitiendo conexiones desde el origen del iframe. Podes necesitar configurar el archivo .htaccess si estás utilizando Apache.